# how to insert logic work on php

Tags: php, insert

i got template php from internet. then i want make other insert. but i dont know this code work
 in code have submit button like this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Добави">
```

and form like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nama</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="required">

   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label> Deskripsi</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Gambar</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" required="required">

   </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label>Harga</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" required="required">

   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>
    Cafe Yang Menjual</label>
    <select name="cafe_id" class="form-control" required="required">

    <option value="">Silahkan Pilih Restoran Yang Akan Menjual Makanan Ini</option>
    <?php foreach($admin->getAllMenus() as $menu) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $menu->id; ?>"><?php echo $menu->nama; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>

    </select>
   </div>
```

and php syntax from that food.php

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $image_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $image=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $image_name=time().$image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($image, "../foods/".strtolower($image_name));
    $_POST["image"]=strtolower($image_name);

    $admin->addFood($_POST);

}
```

and modul code for insert

```
public function addFood($data){
    if($this->db->query("insert into foods(name,image,description,price,cafe_id) values('".$data['name']."','".$data['image']."','".$data['description']."',".$data['price'].",".$data['cafe_id'].")")){



            echo"<script>window.location.href='index.php?page=foods';
            alert('Успешно добавяне на храна');</script>";

        }
        else{
                    echo"<script>window.location.href='index.php?page=foods';
                    alert('Проблем при добавяне на храна');</script>";

        }
```

}

i dont know how that code connect with that submit button. with value `value="Добави"`
that i know is isset($_POST["value submit button"])) but in this code there is `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question but basically a `<form>` HTML element can be used to transfer data to the server, such as:

`<form method="POST" action="food.php">
...
</form>`

Then when the submit method is triggered, the data will be POSTed to `food.php`.

Just to be clear, you need to have PHP installed and running on a webserver before this will work; you can't just copy PHP code into a HTML file and hope it works.

Comment: Further, `$_POST['name']` looks for the element that is *called* 'name' not that has the value 'name'. I.e. the field: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="required">`

Comment: in the value .$data['name']. 'name' is textbox name?

Comment: Yes in the `$_POST` variable, the index is the value of the `name` attribute - e.g. `<input type="text" name="xyz">` -> `$_POST['xyz']`

Comment: It's passing the `$_POST` variable to the `addFood()` function as the `$data` parameter, so essentially, `$data === $_POST`. It is never a good idea to pass data directly from user input into a query but, to answer your question: yes.